# shell script to create backup file when creating new file in particular directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Recently I was asked the following question in an interview.

Suppose I try to create a new file named myfile.txt in the /home/pavan directory.
 It should automatically create myfileCopy.txt in the same directory.
    A.txt then it automatically creates ACopy.txt,
    B.txt then BCopy.txt in the same directory.

How can this be done using a script? I may know that this script should run in crontab.

Please don't use inotify-tools.

Comment: not crontab ... you will need access for that in your account , admins never happy - not easy option ... it could be aliased to be invoked with a command and internally do the stuff for ya ... thats one of the way to do it , offcourse since its unix there are more ways. seems like my sorta question i ask the removal one though!! what else did you try till now ? ...... also this is not a place to be asking interview questions , try something iff you get stuck then ask for help.

Comment: @NSD Every user has their own individual crontab by default;  a sysadmin would have to go way out of their way to disallow it, and I don't think that's particularly common.

Comment: depends on how the is being created. Are you creating it via `echo "foo" > A.txt` or is it being created by invoking `vi` and saving the file? In the latter case it would require some kind of plugin / script that hooks into the `vi` file saving lifecycle.

Comment: @Kevin ...its become a common scenario in a Production server at many projects especially at service based companies. the scenario in which he was asked the question probably corresponds to a similar setting where many applications are present on the same server. Admins don't give anything easy on servers like those ....so using crontab in this case is generally discouraged.

Comment: @pavan Can you explain what you mean by `backup of the file`? Do you want the file to track changes made to original file and update itself automatically? Or just create it when you create a file?

Comment: @NSD I'd still assume cron is an option until and unless the OP specifies otherwise, and since he suggested it it probably is.

Comment: Why don't you just use subversion or a similar service?

Comment: @Kevin , yeah you may be correct .. he did mention crontab in the question so he might be able to use it.

Comment: let me explain suppose i have directory /home/pavan now i create the file myfile.txt in that directory , immediately now i should automatically generate myfileCopy.txt file in the same folder

Comment: @jaypal i just need to create copyFile when we create the file in the particular folder

Comment: @Nick Cox there's a big difference between "improved formatting" and "totally changed the sense of the question". Thus your edit has been rolled back.

Comment: @Nick actually i came to know  inotifywait is one which is used to monitor the Directory. is there any other method where we can handle file event in the directory...so whwn i create a file it auomatically create copy of the same file.

Comment: @msw I agree with the principle. In practice, you rolled back to _my_ revision and undid pavan's edits, so I think the admonition was misplaced.

Comment: The admonition was well placed, that is: don't do that. Thanks for catching my error though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you want to do?

Tools like VIM can create a backup copy of a file you're working on automatically. Other tools like Dropbox (which works on Linux, Windows, and Mac) can *version* files, so it backs up all the copies of the file for the last 30 days.

You could do something by creating aliases to the tools you use for creating these file. You edit a file with the tools you tend to use, and the alias could create a copy before invoking a tool.

Otherwise, your choice is to use crontab to occasionally make backups.

---

#### Addendum

> let me explain suppose i have directory /home/pavan now i create the file myfile.txt in that directory , immediately now i should automatically generate myfileCopy.txt file in the same folder
> paven

There's no easy user tool that could do that. In fact, the way you stated it, it's not clear exactly what you want to do and why. Backups are done for two reasons:

1. To save an older version of the file in case I need to *undo* recent changes. In your scenario, I'm simply saving a new unchanged file.
2. To save a file in case of disaster. I want that file to be located elsewhere: On a different computer, maybe in a different physical location, or at least not on the same disk drive as my current file. In your case, you're making the backup in the same directory.

Tools like VIM can be set to automatically backup a file you're editing. This satisfy reason #1 stated above: To get back an older revision of the file. EMACs could create an infinite series of backups.

Tools like Dropbox create a backup of your file in a different location across the aether. This satisfies reason #2 which will keep the file incase of a disaster. Dropbox also versions files you save which also is reason #1.

Version control tools can also do both, ***if I remember to commit my changes***. They store all changes in my file (reason #1) and can store this on a server in a remote location (reason #2).

I was thinking of crontab, but what would I backup? Backup any file that had been modified (reason #1), but that doesn't make too much sense if I'm storing it in the same directory. All I would have are duplicate copies of files. It would make sense to backup the previous version, but how would I get a simple crontab to know this? Do you want to keep the older version of a file, or only the original copy?

The only real way to do this is at the system level with tools that layer over the disk IO calls. For example, at one location, we used [Netapps](http://www.netapp.com/us/) to create a `$HOME/.snapshot` directory that contained the way your directory looked every minute for an hour, every hour for a day, and every day for a month. If someone deleted a file or messed it up, there was a good chance that the version of the file exists somewhere in the `$HOME/.snapshot` directory.

On my Mac, I use a combination of Time Machine - which backs up the entire drive every hour, and gives me a snapshot of my drive that stretches back over a year and a half) and Dropbox which keeps my files stored in the main Dropbox server somewhere. I've been saved many times by that combination.

I now understand that this was an interview question. I'm not sure what was the position. Did the questioner want you to come up with a system wide way of implementing this, like a network tech position, or was this one of those brain leaks that someone comes up with at the spur of the moment when they interview someone, but were too drunk the night before to go over what they should really ask the applicant?

Did they want a whole discussion on what backups are for, and why backing up a file immediately upon creation in the same directory is a <strike>stupid idea</strike> non-optimal solution, or were they attempting to solve an issue that came up, but aren't technical enough to understand the real issue?

Comment: The OP's original question stated this was asked in an interview -- don't know why someone swoop that off, though.

Comment: @Rubens The question was edited removing that bit of information, so I didn't realize this was an interview question. I would tell the interviewer about tools like NetApps that do snapshots and allow you to restore from snapshots.

Comment: let me explain suppose i have directory /home/pavan now i create the file myfile.txt in that directory , immediately now i should automatically generate myfileCopy.txt file in the same folder